# Custom NDK View on Java Activity?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I need to create a custom view (a 3D object view) using C++ library like [OBJ-Loader](https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader).

I can use this library by setting up Android NDK in my Android Studio Java project. However, once the NDK loads the .OBJ file and creates a 3D Object, how can I show that on my `Activity`?

Is it possible to show the view created by NDK on a normal Java `Activity`? If so, how to pass that data/view to Java? I am aware of how I can pass String/Double/etc. values from NDK to my Java `Activity`.

**Note:** I am trying to avoid [`NativeActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity) because there are other components on the activity that are much easier to do in plain old `Activity`.

Reference to any documentation or guide is appreciated!

Comment: What kind of object is the view that you are creating in the C++ code.

Comment: I haven't tried creating this because I'm not sure if it's possible to do it. I guess the bigger question I have is - is there any type of view that can work? `OBJ-Loader` is an example of C++ library but I can use a different one that allows me to create a supported object/view

Comment: 3D views using OBJ files normally use OpenGL ES. For performance reasons NDK/JNI is used. Resources are available through your favorite search engine.

Comment: @MorrisonChang What resources are you referring to? I already have my `OBJ` file and already have a way to use NDK/JNI to load the 3D object. what I'm asking is little different - is it possible to show what NDK/JNI draws on a normal `Activity`?

Comment: How are you rendering your OBJ file? OBJ files are just text files. The project you linked to just reads in a file and sets up a data structure in C++. No different than reading in a CSV file but does nothing about showing a bar chart of that data. See: [How to load and display .obj file in Android with OpenGL-ES 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41012719/295004) for a Java solution.